# SQL Count(*) Not working in Formula with Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by, average

I can't seem to have my code take the `[Actual Closed Loans]` variable and divide it by the `[Loan Count]` variable.

I tried doing this step in the `[Actual Closing Ratio]` variable. However I get a zero result. Even when I add a new variable to this code and do `1 / count(*)` SQL doesn't seem to like it.

I know I must be using the `Count(*)` incorrectly in this context. But I can't figure it out.

My query:

```
Select
    [PORT_DATE],
    Count (*) as [Loan Count],  --this works fine                               
    sum(Case when [Closed or Fallen Out] ='c' then 1 else 0 end) as [Actual Closed Loans],--this works fine     
    sum(Case when [Closed or Fallen Out] ='C' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as [Actual Closing Ratio], --although code works doesnt produce correct result, output for this variable is all zeros
From 
    dbo.XYZ                                                 
Group by 
    [PORT_DATE]                                     
order by 
    [PORT_DATE]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens due to integer division, add multiplication by `1.0` to get numeric result.

```
sum(Case when [Closed or Fallen Out] ='C' then 1 else 0 end)*1.0/count(*)
```

Comment: In addition, you can cast it to a double.  But I like the `* 1.0`

Comment: @radar, I see your point but what DB does Integer division? I tried Oracle and MySQL and they neither needs the *1.0

Comment: @Dillon, MS SQL server does integer arithmetic.

Comment: Thank yo uso much for your response. The code is working fine now. For others reading this post, the formula was multiplied by 1.0 not 1 ....  Thanks gain!